# Postman gives 'this field already exists' while creating a product object in django rest framework

Tags: django, api, post, django-rest-framework, postman

I am trying to make a post api, where a merchant can add products by selecting category, brand, collection in a merchant dashboard. But when I try to send raw json data from the postman, it says category, brand and collection already existed.

[image]

[image]

My models:

```
class Seller(models.Model):
    seller = models.OneToOneField(
        settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
    business_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True)
    phone_num = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True)

class Product(models.Model):
    
    merchant = models.ForeignKey(Seller,on_delete=models.CASCADE,blank=True,null=True)
    category = models.ManyToManyField(Category, blank=False)
    brand = models.ForeignKey(Brand, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    collection = models.ForeignKey(Collection, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    featured = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

My views:

```
class ProductAddAPIView(CreateAPIView):
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]
    queryset = Product.objects.all()
    serializer_class = AddProductSerializer
```

My serializers:

```
class  AddProductSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    category = CategorySerializer(many=True,required=True)
    brand = BrandSerializer(required=True)
    collection = CollectionSerializer(required=True)
    merchant = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(read_only=True)
    variants = VariantSerializer(many=True,required=True)
    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = ['id','merchant','category','brand', 'collection','featured', 'top_rated',
                  'name','description', 'picture','main_product_image','best_seller',
                  'rating','availability','warranty','services','variants']
        # depth = 1

    def create(self, validated_data):
         user = self.context['request'].user
         category_data = validated_data.pop('category',None)
         brand_data = validated_data.pop('brand',None)
         collection_data = validated_data.pop('collection',None)
         product = Product.objects.create(merchant=user,**category_data,**brand_data,**collection_data)
         return product
```

My urls:

```
path('api/addproducts', views.ProductAddAPIView.as_view(), name='api-addproducts'),
```

Answer (score 1):

```
class AddProductSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    category = CategorySerializer(many=True,required=True)
    brand = BrandSerializer(required=True)
    ....
```

The nested serializers above (like `category`, `brand` fields) are assuming that it is creating new instance/s for category & brand. Even if you pass an `id` because it that field is `read_only` by default in `ModelSerializer` so it never gets included in `validate_data`.

If the use of the serializer is only for writing, I suppose you can use `PrimaryKeyRelatedField`:

```
class AddProductSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    category = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(many=True, required=True, queryset=Category.objects.all())
    brand_id = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(required=True, queryset=Brand.objects.all())

    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = [
            # other fields here
            "brand_id", # previously "brand"
        ]
```

drf docs:
https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#primarykeyrelatedfield